# Leak when calling getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor()

Tags: android

I getting a

```
StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.LeakedClosableViolation: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
```

When using the following code

```
final ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(this.documentFile.getUri(), "r");
FileInputStream is = null;
try {
    is = new FileInputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
    ...
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
}
```

As I'm always closing the inputstream I have no clue what could be causing this

Here's the stack

```
2021-11-03 20:44:35.145 11597-13055/com.xxx D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.LeakedClosableViolation: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidCloseGuardReporter.report(StrictMode.java:1924)
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.warnIfOpen(CloseGuard.java:303)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.finalize(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:1051)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:291)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:278)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.openWithCallSite(CloseGuard.java:259)
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:230)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:208)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$2.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:1111)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$2.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:1102)
        at android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor.<init>(AssetFileDescriptor.java:363)
        at android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(AssetFileDescriptor.java:376)
        at android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(AssetFileDescriptor.java:374)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:784)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1993)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1808)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1641)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1588)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ParcelFileDescriptor object (pfd) needs to be closed as well

Comment: Yepp you can give it a try and see whether it works or not.